# Symfony Demo - unable to sign in

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have upload pushed a Symfony project (based on symfony-demo) to github, however since doing so, I am unable to log in to the demo application as either the demo user or admin - instead I get the the following:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

I have tried the below code as the page advises if the users are not working:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

However, when I submit this I get the following error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]              
  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver  

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]  
  could not find driver
```

I then tried submitting the following in the hope it would fix the doctrine issue:

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
```

However this fed back the following:

```
Using version ^2.2 for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-pdo_sqlite * is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for sensiolabs/security-checker == 2.0.5.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.5].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type into your terminal `php -m`. Do you see `curl`?

If not, it's not installed. Depending on your distro you might do:

RHEL/Centos:

```
yum install php5_curl
```

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
apt-get install php5_curl
```

If not found, try one of the following: `php_curl`, `php-curl`, `php5_curl` or `php5-curl`. Less frequently there is `56` instead of `5`. You could simplify by searching for `curl` and then looking over the list.

Not sure about other distros, but it should be similar.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't have curl installed so got me closer - in case it's of help to anyone else who had the problem, I then just needed to submit `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite` and then I was able to run `composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`

Comment: Great! Glad I could nudge you in a right direction :)