# symfony demo "blog/index.html.twig" error in /var/cache/dev/classes.php

Tags: demo

I set up the demo of symfony ('https://symfony.com/download'). I browse the app in my browser and I receive that error in the log:

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception
>   has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception
>   occured in driver: could not find driver") in "blog/index.html.twig"
>   at line 6." at
>   /usr/local/bin/symfony-project/symfony_demo/var/cache/dev/classes.php
>   line 7607

The line 7607 of the file:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
throw new Twig_Error_Runtime(sprintf('An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("%s").', $e->getMessage()), -1, $template->getTemplateName(), $e);
}
```

I tried to install php-curl because also i cannot log in to the backend of the app([Symfony Demo - unable to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796557/symfony-demo-unable-to-sign-in)). It didnt fix the problem.

Maybe I should try ([What happened after pushing my local repository to github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818199/what-happened-after-pushing-my-local-repository-to-github)). I dont know if in my case I can clear the cache to fix it and how to do it.

Here is the index.html.twig :

```
{% block main %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="{{ path('blog_post', { slug: post.slug }) }}"> {{ post.title }} </a></h2>
        {{ post.summary|md2html }}
    </article>
    {% else %}
        <div class="well">{{ 'post.no_posts_found'|trans }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="navigation text-center"> {{ pagerfanta(posts, 'twitter_bootstrap3_translated', { routeName: 'blog_index_paginated' }) }} </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The first problem come from the line 6 in blog/index.html. Please provide us this file and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: /*line 6*/  {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="post">
            <h2>
                <a href="{{ path('blog_post', { slug: post.slug }) }}">
                    {{ post.title }}
                </a>
            </h2>

            {{ post.summary|md2html }}
        </article>
    {% else %}
        <div class="well">{{ 'post.no_posts_found'|trans }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="navigation text-center">
        {{ pagerfanta(posts, 'twitter_bootstrap3_translated', { routeName: 'blog_index_paginated' }) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

Comment: I edited your post with your code. It will appears in a few minutes.